# Is either of these VB.NET methods faster: SaveSetting() or SetValue()?

Tags: vb.net, registry

I update my app's metrics a lot in registry, and want to know which method of writing to system registry is significantly faster.

Comment: You may just read the first line in [Interaction.SaveSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.savesetting).

Comment: Why even ask?  Is this not something you can test quite easily yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a .NET decompiler to peek into the source code of the `Interaction` class/module under the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, you'll find that the `SaveSetting()` method actually uses `SetValue()` under the hood:<sup>*</sup>

```c#
/// <summary>Saves or creates an application entry in the Windows registry. The My feature gives you greater productivity and performance in registry operations than SaveSetting. For more information, see <see cref="P:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer.Registry" />.</summary>
/// <param name="AppName">Required. String expression containing the name of the application or project to which the setting applies.</param>
/// <param name="Section">Required. String expression containing the name of the section in which the key setting is being saved.</param>
/// <param name="Key">Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting being saved.</param>
/// <param name="Setting">Required. Expression containing the value to which <paramref name="Key" /> is being set.</param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">Key registry could not be created, or user is not logged in.</exception>
/// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
/// <PermissionSet>
///   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
/// </PermissionSet>
public static void SaveSetting(string AppName, string Section, string Key, string Setting)
{
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(AppName);
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(Section);
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(Key);
    string text = Interaction.FormRegKey(AppName, Section);
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(text);
    if (registryKey == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Interaction_ResKeyNotCreated1", new string[]
        {
            text
        }));
    }
    try
    {
        registryKey.SetValue(Key, Setting);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        registryKey.Close();
    }
}
```

Or in VB, if you prefer:

```vb
''' <summary>Saves or creates an application entry in the Windows registry. The My feature gives you greater productivity and performance in registry operations than SaveSetting. For more information, see <see cref="P:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer.Registry" />.</summary>
''' <param name="AppName">Required. String expression containing the name of the application or project to which the setting applies.</param>
''' <param name="Section">Required. String expression containing the name of the section in which the key setting is being saved.</param>
''' <param name="Key">Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting being saved.</param>
''' <param name="Setting">Required. Expression containing the value to which <paramref name="Key" /> is being set.</param>
''' <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">Key registry could not be created, or user is not logged in.</exception>
''' <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
''' <PermissionSet>
'''   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
''' </PermissionSet>
Public Sub SaveSetting(AppName As String, Section As String, Key As String, Setting As String)
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(AppName)
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(Section)
    Interaction.CheckPathComponent(Key)
    Dim text As String = Interaction.FormRegKey(AppName, Section)
    Dim registryKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(text)
    If registryKey Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Interaction_ResKeyNotCreated1", New String() { text }))
    End If
    Try
        registryKey.SetValue(Key, Setting)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        registryKey.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Therefore, I would expect them to have the same performance in this particular case (assuming you will be basically replicating the same behavior). However, the [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry) class (or the [`My.Computer.Registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.servercomputer.registry) property, *which is just a wrapper for the said class*) is going to be more flexible and provides more options as noted in the documentation [(thanks, Jimi!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814152/is-either-of-these-vb-net-methods-faster-savesetting-or-setvalue/56814239#comment100182315_56814152) and in the XML comments shown above.

As to the performance, to be 100% certain (assuming you actually need to), then you should always measure.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>This code was extracted using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).</sub>